# Look up a list of values based on entered values and return all values in the group

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem which I am hoping someone can help me solve using VBA, I have a table that looks like this:

```
 Group No.(Key) | Material
 9400028741 |   600-1014:TELSPEC
 9400028741 |   597/29:TELSPEC
 9400030162 |   BFD328507:ERICSSON
 9400030162 | BFD328507/11:ERICSSON
 9400059657 | BMS 404 030/2:EMERSONRGY
 9400059657 | INV-1000VA RM:CODECOM
 11GHZODU   | GE9234:SIAE
 11GHZODU   | GE9348:SIAE
 12647I     | Q9662A:NEC
 12647I     | Q9662B:NEC
 12653I     | Q9668A:NEC
 12653I     | Q9668B:NEC
```

What I need is to be able to enter a list of materials (from different groups) and then have an output of all the materials that belong to the group for which the materials I entered to begin with belong to.

So if I entered the following materials in A1-A3:

```
 BFD328507:ERICSSON
 Q9668B:NEC
 GE9234:SIAE
```

Then the output would be:

```
 BFD328507:ERICSSON
 BFD328507/11:ERICSSON
 BMS 404 030/2:EMERSONRGY
 INV-1000VA RM:CODECOM
 Q9668B:NEC
 Q9668A:NEC
 Q9662B:NEC
 Q9662A:NEC
 GE9234:SIAE
 GE9348:SIAE
```

Comment: your output isn't correct, the value Q9662B:NEC and Q9662A:NEC haven't the some material group that Q9668B:NEC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is using VBA mandatory? If not then you can just accomplish the task using excel formulas itself.
Here's what I think may help: Consider following data.

```
Group No(A1)|Material(B1)|Enter Material(C1)|GetGroupNo(D1)|Final_List(E1)
1|Mat_1
1|Mat_1.1
1|Mat_1.2
2|Mat_2
2|Mat_2.1
3|Mat_3
3|Mat_3.1
3|Mat_3.2
3|Mat_3.3
4|Mat_4
5|Mat_5
5|Mat_5.1
```

1. In cell C2 ***Enter your material for lookup***
2. In cell D2 enter formula ***=LOOKUP(C2,B:B,A:A)***
3. In cell E3 enter formula ***=IF(A:A=D$2,B:B,"")***

Now you have a list of all materials belonging to that group.